# Exporting 1.5 million records from File Geodatabase to Microsoft Access table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, ms-access

I have a table that I want to export from arcmap that has around 1.5 million records. I need to import it into access. Now every time I have tried to export it into a format that access will read, like a csv or dbase, the records become corrupted and instead of displaying there values i they have contents such as "3.186345345345-3".

Does anyone know of a way to export to access that will work perfectly?

Comment: what is the original table format?

Comment: @U2ros It is in a gdb.

Comment: @MikeSzp. Is it an ArcGIS 10 File GDB? Or on SDE? Also, how many columns are you looking at (and how big are those columns)? Unfortunately access itself has a [2GB file size limit](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) that you might need to worry about...

Comment: @om_henners the database has about 50 cloumns, it is arcGIS 10.1 and it is in a GDB right now. If filesize is  an issue then I can export it in two peices later, I just can't export at all right now without corruption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking to get your data into an access database you could skip the middle conversion step entirely (or rather have ArcGIS handle it for you) by transferring your data to a personal geodatabase, which in reality [is an access database](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018s0000000n000000).

From ArcGIS you can use the [Create Personal Geodatabase tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000q0000000) to create the access database, and then you should be able to just copy your data across (though I'd export a table to geodatabase and copy the table so you don't waste memory and copy geometries if you don't need them).

Alternately (depending on your version of access) if you already have a database (as .mdb) you don't need to create files to copy them across.

Alternately if you're comfortable with command line utilities [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/) supports [FileGDB](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html) and various other [formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) including [CSV](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html), so you can dump your data out of your geodatabase using [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).